# Upload multiple files in one form MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

I'm trying to upload multiple images on one form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "AdminRestaurants", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="logoFile" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Logo:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="file" multiple="" name="logoFile" id="logoFile" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="fohFile" class="col-sm-2 control-label">FOH Logo:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="file" multiple="" name="fohFile" id="fohFile" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="bohFile" class="col-sm-2 control-label">BOH Logo:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="file" multiple="" name="bohFile" id="bohFile" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="mgmFile" class="col-sm-2 control-label">MGM Logo:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="file" multiple="" name="mgmFile" id="mgmFile" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to process the form on the controller with this

```
public ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, RestaurantModel collection)
{
    if (ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    }
}
```

Currently nothing shows up in the `files` signature on the controller. This seems to work great when only working with one file

```
public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase file, EventsModel collection)
```

Can someone point me in the direction to allow multiple files to be uploaded with one submission form?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your problem is that you form creates a post request with information that the model binder can bind because the naming convention is not right.

you see, you have 4 file fields each with a different name, for the model binder to bind them correctly your controller action signature should look like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase mgmFile, 
                           HttpPostedFileBase logoFile, 
                           HttpPostedFileBase fohFile ,
                           HttpPostedFileBase bohFile)
```

Following MCV design pattern The best option would be to use a ViewModel that holds an `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>` 
and you would create a custom editor template for an `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>`

so that you could use it like that:

```
Html.EditorFor(m=>Model.filesUploaded)
```

and your controller action would look like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(MyViewModel i_InputModel)
{
    i_InputModel.filesUploade; //Use the files here to upload them.
}
```

**Other options are:**
Use the HTML5 multiple attribute on the file input field like this:

```
<label for="mgmFile" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Files:</label>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files" id="files" />
</div>
```

and a controller action like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase files)
```

or use multiple file fields but index them in their name:

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files[0]" id="files_1" />
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files[1]" id="files_2" />
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files[2]" id="files_3" />
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files[3]" id="files_4" />
```

and then you could use a controller action like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
```

Comment: the last solution with the index name worked perfect for me. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This would only work if your file inputs had indexed names like `files[0]`, `files[1]`, `files[2]`,...

In order to understand how model binding to a list works in asp.net mvc, I recommend that you read this post: [Model Binding to a List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

You don't even have to use model binding to get the files. Use `Request.Files` in your Action to get them.

```
public ActionResult Create(EventsModel collection)
{
    var files = Request.Files;
    // rest of the code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
      <input type="file" name="files" id="files" multiple="multiple" />
      </td>
```

As Here, I demonstrate with simple example : http://www.infinetsoft.com/Post/How-to-create-multiple-fileUpload-using-asp-net-MVC-4/1229#.V0J-yfl97IU