# Recognize input type file from Request.Files in Asp.net MVC using Angular JS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, input-type-file

I have two input type file controls in my view page . One is for Avatar and the other is for profile image. And I am getting both images in code behind.
Here is my AngularJS controller

```
    var app = angular.module('ProfileModule', []);
app.controller('ProfileController',['$scope','$http', function ($scope,$http) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.files = [];
    var formData = new FormData();
    $scope.LoadFileData = function (files) {
        for (var file in files) {
            formData.append("file", files[file]);
        }
    };
    $scope.submit = function () {
        $http({
            url: "/Profiles/Edit",
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": undefined },
            transformRequest: function (data) {
                formData.append("user", angular.toJson(data.user));
                //for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
                //    formData.append("files[" + i + "]", data.files[i]);
                //}
                return formData;
            },
            data: { user: $scope.user }
        })
        .success(function (response) { });
    }
}]);
```

Here are the two controls

```
<input id="selector" type="file"   onchange="angular.element(this).scope().LoadFileData(this.files)" accept="image/*">



<input id="selector" type="file"   onchange="angular.element(this).scope().LoadFileData(this.files)" accept="image/*">
```

Here is my MVC controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(string user, HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
        {}
```

I am getting rest model value in string and later parsing that to model but images file showing null in files so I am getting them in Request.Files .
What edit should I do to get that images file in the array.

Comment: Your input elements should have unique ids, just like any other elements should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your input type file controls should have name attributes set to something like "profileImage" and "avatarImage". Then define your controller action like so:

```
[HttpPost]
ActionResult Edit (string user, HttpPostedFileBase profileImage, HttpPostedFileBase avatarImage)
{
...
}
```

And html:

```
<input id="selector" name="profileImage" type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().LoadFileData(this.files)" accept="image/*"> 

<input id="selector" name="avatarImage" type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().LoadFileData(this.files)" accept="image/*">
```

EDIT: Check if the parameters are non-null and you are ready to go.

EDIT: added user parameter to controller action.

EDIT: added html code.

Comment: Have you also added the name attributes to your inputs?

Comment: Yes I have added that there must be a problem in transform request and data in http post .

Comment: Also fix the identical ids before trying again, please.

Comment: I am getting two images in Request.File but null in arguments

Comment: Yes checked that also changing ids also

Answer (score 0):

You can just tweak your controller action to accept an `IEnumerable` of `HttpPostedFileBase` instances:

```
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
```

If you want to upload several file fields each with a different name, for the model binder to bind them correctly your controller action signature should look like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase avatar, 
                           HttpPostedFileBase profile)
```

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208223/upload-multiple-files-in-one-form-mvc4)

Comment: Suppose if user input only one image how would I know to place that in avatar or profile?